# How to remove element from array in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

How do I remove element from array through index in VHDL?

```
type ROM_Array is array (0 to 2) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal operand : ROM_Array:= (0=>b"11000000100000000000000000000000",
                                1=>b"01000000110000000000000000000000",                                        2=>b"01000000010000000000000000000000");
```

For example I want to remove (delete) element with [index 1, operand(1)]. How?

Comment: You need to define a new array type with a smaller range and declare a new signal of new array type that you can use from old to new array.

Comment: but how to pass element of old array to new array except what I want to delete ?

Comment: All the elements of an array type have the same subtype. You can't have one with one fewer 'bits'.  `signal new_operand: std_logic_vector (30 downto 0); where new_operand <= operand(1)(31 downto 2) & operand(1)(0);` new_operand can be of the subtype of a new operand array subtype. Provide a [mcve] so any answerer can demonstrate a working answer (which the first answer does not). Your question isn't clear as is. You could say left justify the value assigned to new_operand as an element of a rom_array value should you be able to define the used length by content. Show your intent.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to define a new array type with a smaller range and declare a new signal of new array type that you can use from old to new array.

First, we declare here a new array with the same type and size as the original array, minus one.

Example;

```
type New_ROM_Array is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal new_operand : New_ROM_Array;
```

Then copy the elements from the original array to the new array, skipping the element at the index to remove.
Here, it skip element at index 1.

```
new_operand(0) <= operand(0);
new_operand(1) <= operand(2);
```

The above copy the 1st and 3rd element from `operand` to `new_operand`, effectively removing the second element.

This `operand <= new_operand;` is similar to **splice**. We use this to changes the contents of array by removing existing elements and/or adding new one.

> but how to pass element of old array to new array except what I want to delete ?

You can loop and check the index of the element. If the index is not the one you want to remove, copy it in new array.

```
process
begin
 for i in operand'range loop
   if i /= 1 then -- Skip the element at index 1
     new_operand(i - 1) <= operand(i);
   end if;
 end loop;
end process;
```

You can try the above approach as I know that you can't directly remove an element from an array like you can do in some other pl because vhdl arrays are static and their size is determined at the time of declaration.